# Adding class constraints to typeclass instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to implement the Cantor Pairing Function, as an instance of a
generic Pair typeclass, as so:

```
module Pair (Pair, CantorPair) where

-- Pair interface
class Pair p where
    pi :: a -> a -> p a
    k :: p a -> a
    l :: p a -> a

-- Wrapper for typing
newtype CantorPair a = P { unP :: a }

-- Assume two functions with signatures:
cantorPair :: Integral a => a -> a -> CantorPair a
cantorUnpair :: Integral a => CantorPair a -> (a, a)

-- I need to somehow add an Integral a constraint to this instance,
-- but I can't work out how to do it.
instance Pair CantorPair where
    pi = cantorPair
    k = fst . cantorUnpair
    l = snd . cantorUnpair
```

How can I add the appropriate Integral constraint to the instance?
I have a vague feeling I might need to modify the Pair interface itself,
but not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want all pairs to always contain integral elements? In this case, you could add the constraint to the signatures of the methods:

```
class Pair p where
  pi :: Integral i => i -> i -> p i
  k :: Integral i => p i -> i
  l :: Integral i => p i -> i
```

This will make you pair class less general but will ensure that your `CantorPair` type could be a part of it.

If you want to keep your `Pair` class somewhat general, you could use a multi parameter type class. (This will require two extensions: `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `FlexibleInstances`.)

```
class Pair p a where
  pi :: a -> a -> p a
  k :: p a -> a
  l :: p a -> a

instance Integral i => Pair CantorPair i where
    pi = cantorPair
    k = fst . cantorUnpair
    l = snd . cantorUnpair
```

I don't know if this is necessarily the best option from a design standpoint, but it's a good way to learn about how multiparamter type classes work. (Which, admittedly, is fairly simple.)

Comment: Well, at this stage I think I will always be using Integrals, but I didn't think it made sense to add that constraint to Pair.

For example, another instance could be added such as

    data IdentityPair a = I a a
    instance Pair IdentityPair where
        pi x y = I x y
        k (I x _) = x
        l (I _ y) = y

Comment: Aah, thanks! I thought I'd need MultiParamTypeClasses, but couldn't get my fiddling to work. Must've been because I wasn't using FlexibleInstances.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the class definition, you can add an `Integral` constraint to the `pi`, `k`, and `l` methods. This is a bit unsatisfactory, though: there's nothing saying that `Integral` is going to be the right constraint for all instances, and you after all don't want to reject some instances just because you didn't have enough foresight. So, here's one generalization: we'll allow the constraint to vary in each instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies #-}
import GHC.Exts

newtype CantorPair a = P { unP :: a }
cantorPair :: Integral a => a -> a -> CantorPair a
cantorUnpair :: Integral a => CantorPair a -> (a, a)
cantorPair = undefined
cantorUnpair = undefined

class Pair p where
    type Ctxt p a :: Constraint
    pi :: Ctxt p a => a -> a -> p a
    k  :: Ctxt p a => p a -> a
    l  :: Ctxt p a => p a -> a

instance Pair CantorPair where
    type Ctxt CantorPair a = Integral a
    pi = cantorPair
    k  = fst . cantorUnpair
    l  = snd . cantorUnpair

-- just for fun
data DataPair a = DataPair a a

instance Pair DataPair where
    type Ctxt DataPair a = ()
    pi = DataPair
    k (DataPair a _) = a
    l (DataPair _ a) = a

-- this one made GHC panic! neat, I get to file a bug
data Unit a = Unit

instance Pair Unit where
    type Ctxt Unit a = a ~ ()
    pi _ _ = Unit
    k _ = ()
    l _ = ()
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses [type families](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-families.html), so you need `-XTypeFamilies`. We put the type constraint on the type itself, instead of the type constructor:

```
class Pair p where
    type First p :: *
    type Second p :: *
    pi :: First p -> Second p -> p
    k :: p -> First p
    l :: p -> Second p
```

and then we create the instances like:

```
instance Integral a => Pair (CantorPair a) where
    type First (CantorPair a) = a
    type Second (CantorPair a) = a
    pi = cantorPair
    k = fst . cantorUnpair
    l = snd . cantorUnpair

instance Pair (a, b) where
    type First (a, b) = a
    type Second (a, b) = b
    pi = (,)
    k = fst
    l = snd
```