# How to add typeclass constraints to a newtype expression?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, newtype

I am reading the book *Haskell Programming from First Principles* and there is an exercise in the `newtype` chapter, asking me to make a `TooMany` instance for `(Num a, TooMany a) => (a, a)`.

The exercises before this one have already made `TooMany` instances for `Int`, `Goats Int`, `(Int, String)` and `(Int, Int)`. I have done these ones but not for `(Num a, TooMany a) => (a, a)`.

All codes follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class TooMany a where
  tooMany :: a -> Bool

instance TooMany Int where
  tooMany n = n > 42

newtype Goats = Goats Int deriving (Eq, Show, TooMany)

-- the following needs FlexibleInstances pragma
instance TooMany (Int, String) where
  tooMany (n, _) = n > 33

-- or do this:
newtype AnotherTooMany = AnotherTooMany (Int, String) deriving (Eq, Show, TooMany)

instance TooMany (Int, Int) where
  tooMany (n, m) = (n + m) > 44


-- THE FOLLOWING ONES ARE NOT CORRECT !!!

instance TooMany (Num a, TooMany a) => (a, a) where
  tooMany (t1, t2) = (t1 + t2) > 44

newtype YetAnotherTooMany =
  YetAnotherTooMany (Num a, TooMany a) => (a, a)
  deriving (Eq, Show, TooMany)
```

How should I change the last two expressions to make them work?

I also referred to the following questions, but still not found an answer:

[Adding class constraints to typeclass instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397751/adding-class-constraints-to-typeclass-instance)

[Can a typeclass constraint be used in a newtype definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444170/can-a-typeclass-constraint-be-used-in-a-newtype-definition)

Comment: `instance (Num a, TooMany a) => TooMany (a, a)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal change would be like this:

```
instance (Num a, Ord a, TooMany a) => TooMany (a, a) where
    tooMany (t1, t2) = (t1 + t2) > 44
```

Two notes about this instance: I had to add an `Ord` constraint because of the call to `(>)`, and the `TooMany` constraint is redundant because the implementation does not call `tooMany` with an `a` as an argument. I suspect the intended exercise solution has a slightly different implementation of the `tooMany` method -- I encourage you to try to find a way to implement this using the `TooMany a` constraint and without using the `Ord a` constraint!

For your `newtype`, the correct syntax is this:

```
newtype YetAnotherTooMany a = YetAnotherTooMany (a, a)
    deriving (Eq, Show, TooMany)
```

You would need to delete the `(Int, Int)` instance of `TooMany` for this exact syntax to work, as otherwise there are overlapping instances to choose during deriving. However, I expect the intended exercise solution is to write the instance yourself for this `newtype` under the assumption that the `(a, a)` instance does not exist at all -- since presumably the goal is to learn how to use `newtype` to avoid overlapping instance problems in the first place.